# Android phonegap file://android_asset/www/index.htm

Tags: android, cordova

I am building a mobile application with PhoneGap and Android, I have a loader at the start of the app and I am loading 2 images on startup, whenever the network speed is slow the following message pops-up and the app crashes:

The connection to the server was unsuccessful. `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`

Is there anyway to handle this error, that is, display for the user a message like "connection problem please try again" instead of the above message?

Your help is very much appreciated as I tried a lot and I went for `super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);` but I need a better solution.

Comment: the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319809/application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-file-andr

Answer (score 1):

The path shoule be:
"file:///android_asset/www/index.html"

seems you miss a slash