# Handle resources and images timeout in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

Hello guys,

I'm working on an app based on Ionic - so AngularJS. In my testing of the app I connected my device to a very slow wifi, to test how the app responds... It's awful, but not too bad because the problem is very localised.

At first the app wouldn't load at all. `Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded` appears in the console, and an alert shows `Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)`.

I followed the tip here : [increase loadUrlTimeoutValue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31377846/1928380)

The app stopped crashing. BUT it would remain on a white screen, until eventually the only http call in the index.html fails :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&libraries=places
```

The console logs `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT` and the app bootstraps like usual. Second thing, the images that has to be displayed in the gallery of the app won't show up, getting me a bunch of `408 (Request Time-out)` after a long load time, for example

```
GET http://res.cloudinary.com/myimage.jpg 408 (Request Time-out)
```

So my guess is, on this very slow wifi, all http calls are an issue - they simply fail after some time and returns an error that the console is able to display.

My simple question : how to catch that type of error globally to be able to display a message to the user ? Or even better, listen to any http call and timeout myself after 5s or so to display the said message ?

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 0):

Angulars [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service has a `timeout` property in config argument. You can set it to 5s (5000 as it is in miliseconds). Then you can handle timeout in error callback.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know about this, but it won't help, really, since I'm not invoking anywhere the $http service. As I said, it's a script tag calling the maps api, and img tags with their url argument.

Comment: Not an issue of Angular, no, but a way to handle this globally is not something theorically strange - maybe a global config to set or something I didn't hear about yet... Anyway, a regular Javascript way could potentially lead to a solution as well.