# Ionic App Launch Error it shows "Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)"

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I launches my Ionic App on android platform it shows me error Sometimes that

> Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

and then App crashes after trying 5 to 6 times then App loaded. How to fix this error 
As some people suggested i am not having any external javascript links all are downloaded in project .
my index file

**index.html**

```
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- Web client for push Notification-->
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/externalLibrary/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="js/externalLibrary/ng-cordova.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="lib/logtofile/www/logtofile.js"></script> -->


<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/externalLibrary/mqttws31.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/externalLibrary/ion-pullup.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/menuContent.js"></script>
<!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
<!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="app/constant/constant.js"></script>
<script src="app/constant/string.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/TrackingApi.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/errorHandling.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/shareData.js"></script>
<script src="app/geofencetoolkit/geofenceCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/geofencetoolkit/geofenceeditCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/vtracking/VTrackingCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/vtracking/trackingCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/DataPassService.js"></script>

<script src="app/walktocar/walktocarCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/adddevice/deviceCtrl.js"></script>

<script src="app/settings/settingsCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/loginPage/loginPageCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/addAccount/jioLoginCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/addAssignee/addAssigneeCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/carList/carListingCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/homePage/homePageCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/dashboard/dashboardCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/patrolLevel/patrolLevelCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/coolantTemp/coolantTempCtrl.js"></script>
```

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.harman.jiocarconnected" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Jio Car Connect</name>
  <description>&#xD;&#xD;
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.&#xD;&#xD;
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">&#xD;&#xD;
      Ionic Framework Team&#xD;&#xD;
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <access origin="cdvfile://*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="17000" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan"/>
  <!-- <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/> -->
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#009c84"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent"/>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20"/>
  <hook type="before_run" src="hooks/appBeforeBuild.js" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>

  </platform>
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android\_asset/www/index.html)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319809/application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-file-andr)

Answer (score 0):

All the Javascript , Css files Should be called with in the application , Should not be Called from the Web , There are three reasons for this bug

- Should not Call the Javascript or Css Files from web if You want to call make Sure **internet is working** on your device ,
- may be some Important JS Files are missing
- Files Which is Called inside the index.html could be Crashed or Missing

Comment: all files are internal as you can see my index.html above l

Comment: I have Faced the Same Issue ...   Can u check with full internet Connection

Comment: In full internet connection it works fine but how to handle for the case of low connectivity

Answer (score 0):

There are two things

1. You get this error when your index.html has to load a js or css from a web server and it has no connectivity, like a script tag pointing to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js
2. The order of your js scripts, can you cordova js first, the jquery and then ionic. This is for the dependencies to load properly

Comment: Still getting the same error after implementing this .

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your config.xml

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
```