# Ionic App Fails to Run On Android Device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to run an Ionic app on my android tablet but I'm getting the following error message on my device when I run the command:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Application Error: Connection to the server was unsuccessful (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Then when I run command:

```
ionic cordova run android --device --livereload
```

I get this error - Application Error: Connection to the server was unsuccessful (*IP ADDRESS*)

When running the app on an iOS device it works perfectly, but for whatever reason this error is preventing me from testing on Android devices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319809/application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-file-andr